# cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.TextCell' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a ViewCell that has elements TextCell and SwitchCell.
This is my Code-

```
<ListView x:Name="AlarmList" HasUnevenRows="True" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextCell TextColor="#CCCCCC" Text="{Binding Name}" DetailColor="Red" Detail="{Binding Address}"></TextCell>
                        <SwitchCell />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

the Error i get is:

> cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.TextCell' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View'

The Alternative to this is using these

```
<Label ></Label>
<Switch ></Switch>
```

Is there any other way to achieve Something like this.? 

[image]

Comment: Cells can only be used in Lists and Tables, they cannot be nested within other Layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `StackLayout` expects a `View` object, which is basically any UI element, but not `Cell`s. You can either use the predefined cells that come with Xamarin Forms, if you want to defer from that you are stuck with composing your own layout.

You're off to a good start, but you cannot use cells. So lose them, and layout the `ViewCell` whatever way you want.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested a `ViewCell` can only contain non-Cell Forms elements. To correct your `ViewCell` do it like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="AlarmList" HasUnevenRows="True" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label TextColor="#CCCCCC" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Switch />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```